# Python - Create new variables using list

Tags: python, list, variables

I would like to create new variables from a list.

For example:

```
mylist=[A,B,C]
```

From which i would like to create the following variables:

```
self.varA
self.varB
self.varC
```

How can create these new variables in a loop?

Answer (score 6):

```
mylist=['A','B','C']
for name in mylist:
    setattr(self, name, None)
```

but this is nearly always a bad idea and the values should be in a dict like:

```
self.v = {}
for name in mylist:
    self.v[name] = None
```

Comment: +1, and just because you can do something in Python doesn't mean you should

Answer (score 0):

Your question ignores the fact that the variables need values ... who is going to supply what values how?  Here is a solution to *one* of the possible clarified questions:

With this approach, the caller of your constructor can use either a dict or keyword args to pass in the names and values.

```
>>> class X(object):
...     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
...         for k in kwargs:
...             setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
...

# using a dict

>>> kandv = dict([('foo', 'bar'), ('magic', 42), ('nix', None)])
>>> print X(**kandv).__dict__
{'nix': None, 'foo': 'bar', 'magic': 42}

# using keyword args

>>> print X(foo='bar', magic=42, nix=None).__dict__
{'nix': None, 'foo': 'bar', 'magic': 42}
```

Comment: I actually managed to get it right with  setattr and getattr in the following manner:
for c in curlist:     
            setattr(self, "penum"+c, 0)
                  …
                  …
valuel=getattr(self,(entlistnum[n]+curlist[c]))
                    setattr(self,(entlistnum[n]+curlist[c]),valuel+1)

In any case, thank you for your valuable explanation.